# Two column document with the table intruding into the second column

Tags: tables, two-column, article

I'm currently having this issue where the table is intruding into the second column and I can't figure out what I've done wrong...

[image: table intruding on second column]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} p{5.3cm} } 
\hline 
Parameter & Condition \\
\hline
Flow Rate & $4.5 \frac{\text{mL}}{\text{min}}$ \\
Carrier gas & Nitrogen \\
Column type & HP-$5$  \\
Column dimensions & \SI{10}{m} long $\times$ \SI{0.53}{mm} ID  \\
Injection port temperature & \SI{140}{\celsius}  \\
Oven temperature & \SI{40}{\celsius} \\
Attenuation & Automatically done by computer \\
Sample size & $\num{3.00000e-1}\frac{\text{ng}}{\text{ul}}$ \\
Number of products & $2$  \\ 
Types of products & Butenes \\  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space[1ex]
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does not `p{5cm} p{5.3cm}` give you a clue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please after you copy the code from your editor to the window, select all the pasted code and press `{}` button instead of placing every line in code...

Comment: I've tried removing them or changing the proportions and the text gets very messy. 
sorry I'm relatively new to LaTeX

Comment: just add \usepackage{siunitx} in your preamble

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten to include that in the code that I had shared with you. It is already there in my preamble.

Comment: @ChristopherG, It is better to add the picture using the appropriate button than to uploadin on i.stack.imgur.com and add the link. If you try to edit you will recognize this button. Also, a `\lipsum` command could help to make obvious your problem, because without text nothing overlaps with the table

Answer (score 5):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,lipsum}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}} 
\toprule 
Parameter & Condition \\
\midrule
Flow Rate & $4.5 \frac{\text{mL}}{\text{min}}$ \\
Carrier gas & Nitrogen \\
Column type & HP-$5$  \\
Column dimensions & \SI{10}{m} long $\times$ \SI{0.53}{mm} ID  \\
Injection port temperature & \SI{140}{\celsius}  \\
Oven temperature & \SI{40}{\celsius} \\
Attenuation & Automatically done by computer \\
Sample size & $\num{3.00000e-1}\frac{\text{ng}}{\text{ul}}$ \\
Number of products & $2$  \\ 
Types of products & Butenes \\  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space[1ex]
\bottomrule %inserts single line
\end{tabular*}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Edit: To have a table taking two columns but without using `table*` environment to avoid the jump to the next page, you can use `cuted` and `capt-of` packages:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,lipsum,cuted,capt-of}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\section{Nulla malesuada} 
\lipsum[3]
\begin{strip}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}} 
\toprule 
Parameter & Condition \\
\midrule
Flow Rate & $4.5 \frac{\text{mL}}{\text{min}}$ \\
Carrier gas & Nitrogen \\
Column type & HP-$5$  \\
Column dimensions & \SI{10}{m} long $\times$ \SI{0.53}{mm} ID  \\
Injection port temperature & \SI{140}{\celsius}  \\
Oven temperature & \SI{40}{\celsius} \\
Attenuation & Automatically done by computer \\
Sample size & $\num{3.00000e-1}\frac{\text{ng}}{\text{ul}}$ \\
Number of products & $2$  \\ 
Types of products & Butenes \\  
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*}
\captionof{table}{GC parameters on}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Nam dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked! The Text is no longer overlapping into the second column.
Would you be able to explain those tabular parameters you set?

Comment: Also, Is there a way to set up the table so the text for each column is on one line?

Comment: @Christopher. Non one, but two:  (1) change `table` by `table*`  (two times)  (2) `\tiny
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\dimexpr.4\linewidth-\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.6\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}} `. Using (1) the table will appear in top of the next page.

Comment: So how would you go about maintaining the table within the same section? as in not on a new page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use environment `table*` to get a table going over both columns ...

The the following MWE (important code changings marked with `<======`)

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{blindtext} % <======= dummy text ===========================

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}


\begin{document}
\Blindtext Code for the table
\begin{table*}[ht] % <==================================================
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} p{5.3cm} } 
\hline 
Parameter & Condition \\
\hline
Flow Rate & $4.5 \frac{\text{mL}}{\text{min}}$ \\
Carrier gas & Nitrogen \\
Column type & HP-$5$  \\
Column dimensions & \SI{10}{m} long $\times$ \SI{0.53}{mm} ID  \\
Injection port temperature & \SI{140}{\celsius}  \\
Oven temperature & \SI{40}{\celsius} \\
Attenuation & Automatically done by computer \\
Sample size & $\num{3.00000e-1}\frac{\text{ng}}{\text{ul}}$ \\
Number of products & $2$  \\ 
Types of products & Butenes \\  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space[1ex]
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table*} % <========================================================
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

and the resulting second page:

[image: second page]

Answer (score 1):

an alternative:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{@{}l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}@{}}
\hline
Parameter & Condition \\
\hline
Flow Rate & $4.5 \frac{\text{mL}}{\text{min}}$ \\
Carrier gas & Nitrogen \\
Column type & HP-$5$  \\
Column dimensions & \SI{10}{m} long $\times$ \SI{0.53}{mm} ID  \\
Injection port temperature & \SI{140}{\celsius}  \\
Oven temperature & \SI{40}{\celsius} \\
Attenuation & Automatically done by computer \\
Sample size & $\num{3.00000e-1}\frac{\text{ng}}{\text{ul}}$ \\
Number of products & $2$  \\
Types of products & Butenes \\  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space[1ex]
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to keep the table in the desired section {i.e. not on a new page, but within the text)?

Comment: if on the page is enough space for table, it is where is inserted.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine `tabularx`, a `\small` font size, and a smaller value of `\tabcolsep`. Also, I use the rules from `booktabs`, which incorporates some vertical padding, and  I simplified the code with the help of `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{amsmath, lipsum, siunitx, tabularx, booktabs}
\DeclareSIUnit\min{min}
\DeclareSIUnit\ng{ng}
\DeclareSIUnit\Ul{ul}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}%}
\toprule
Parameter & Condition \\
\midrule
Flow Rate & \SI{4.5}{\mL\per\min} \\
Carrier gas & Nitrogen \\
Column type & HP-$5$ \\
Column dimensions & \SI{10}{m} long $\times$ \SI{0.53}{mm} ID \\
Injection port temperature & \SI{140}{\celsius} \\
Oven temperature & \SI{40}{\celsius} \\
Attenuation & Automatically done by computer \\
Sample size & \SI{3.00000e-1}{\ng\per\Ul} \\
Number of products & $2$ \\
Types of products & Butenes \\
\bottomrule %inserts single line
\end{tabularx}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]